# Suggestions for Building a URL

Tags: 7

I am working on a custom module that has a search form with an advanced search. The search will display results for a specific content type (digital documents).

The possible search options are:

- Query
- Language
- Subject Area
- Categories
- Tags

I've set up the module to build the advanced search form based on the widget of the field on the content type. So for example, the language widget is set to checkboxes so the module creates checkboxes on the advanced search form. This works great and allows the user to modify how the advanced search form works.

Currently after submit, I store all of my search values into the session. This works great. The form and search results are output in a block, there is no page output. This allows the user to manage the URL through Drupal rather than the module.

The latest request from the client is for the ability to link directly to a subject area and category. Something like /documents/subject_area or documents/category. Since the module is so flexible and I want it to be possible for the user to link to any combination of options I need to build the URL is such a way that the user can do that.

Obviously I would like to avoid a giant URL mess and would like clean looking URL's. But how do I accomplish this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mean, if you goto path `foo` you get a listing of documents meeting that search criteria, I'd suggest something like `documents/CRITERIA/SPECIFIC` eg `documents/language/english`, `documents/subject/matter` or `documents/category/whatever`.  granted, this doesn't address finding english documents in category whatever, but for that I really think you'd be looking at the crazed url and query string the search module creates :)

Comment: Why aren't you using the Form API?

Comment: I am using the Form API. So what if I had a link to two categories and a language? /documents/category1/category2/language whould be almost impossible to parse reliably...

Comment: /document/category/cat1/category/cat2/language/lang is an option where "category" tells me that the next piece is a category and "language" tells me that the next piece is a language...how does that sound?